# Comportamento Inesperado, Operador Lógico XOR - PHP

Tags: php, operadores

porquê é possível ver este comportamento do operador lógico `xor`?

```
$bool = false xor true;
var_dump($bool); // bool(false) 

$bool = true xor false;
var_dump($bool); // bool(true)
```

pelo que li, `xor` deveria retornar true apenas se um ou outro é verdadeiro, mas não ambos(exclusividade), sendo assim, não deveria retornar tudo `boolean(true)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O primeiro caso está retornando `false` porque o operador `=` tem precedência sobre o operador `xor`.

```
$bool = false xor true; // false
```

Ao invés disso, faça assim:

```
$bool = (false xor true); // true
```

Fonte: [PHP: Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: uau, então teve uma briga de operadores diferentes, um de atribuição e outro de lógica, e o de atribuição saiu na frente. uffa, agora ficou mais claro, obrigado Rodrigo!

Comment: É isso mesmo! Para ver como o operador `xor` está ok, faça simplesmente um `var_dump(false xor true)`.